# LinqPad: how do I get help on a user defined assembly?

Tags: linqpad

I have added a user defined assembly to query properties.
Now when using a function I don't see its documentation in Intellisense although I have specified `<summary>` and `<remarks>` tags.
Does LinqPad support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view XML documentation from a custom assembly in LinqPad you need to ensure the following are in place:

1. You have a licensed version of LinqPad - IntelliSense is a paid for option.
2. Your custom assembly has an XML documentation file. To ensure this is created during your build process, open the project properties, select the Build tab and tick "XML Documentation File"